# changing the id of elements dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
                <span class="label-input100">Year *</span>
                <div>
                    <select class="js-select2" id="year0" name="year[]" onchange="selectMake()" >
                        <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
                        <option>2018</option>
                        <option>2017</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
                <span class="label-input100">Make *</span>
                <div>
                    <select class="js-select2" id="make0" name="make[]" onchange="selectModel()">
                        <option value="">Please chooses Make</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <div class="wrap-input100" id="add_vehical_section"> </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
                <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_vehical">
                    <span>
                        Add another Vehicle
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is my html code

```
 <script>
 var i=0;
     function selectMake() 
     {
    $("#year"+ i +"").change(function () 
    {
        var y = $(this).val();
        if(y == "2018") 
        {
            $("#make"+ i +"").html("<option value='make1'>make 1</option><option value='make2'>make 2</option>");
        } 
        else if(y == "2017")
        {
            $("#make"+ i +"").html("<option value='make3'>make 3</option><option value='make4'>make 4</option>");
        } 
    }
);} </script>
            <script>
 var i=1;
 $("#add_vehical").click(function () {  
 $( "#add_vehical_section").replaceWith("<div class='wrap-input100 input100- 
 select bg1'><span class='label-input100'>Year *</span><div><select 
 class='js-select2' id='year"+ i +"' name='year[]' onchange='selectMake()'> 
 <option value=''>Please choose Year</option> <option>2018</option> 
 <option>2017</option></select><div class='dropDownSelect2'></div></div> 
 </div><div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'><span class='label- 
  input100'>Make *</span><div><select class='js-select2' id='make"+ i +"' 
   name='make[]' onchange='selectModel()'><option value=''>Please chooses 
  Make</option></select><div class='dropDownSelect2'></div></div></div>");  
 i++;
 });

 </script>
```

this is my javascript. 
i need to change the id of year and make everytime the add vehicle is clicked. this program changes the value of the second select tag based on the value of the first select. what is wrong with my code?? different id is required so as to make the function selectMake() work.what is wrong with my code?? please help me out.

Comment: I could not completely understand what you need. What is the error in your code exactly? Could you also please provide input data and expected output? Please EDIT your question, and avoid posting comments to your own question, unless necessary. Thanks

Comment: In summary, *don't*.  Instead create another/as many as needed inputs and show/hide them as needed.  This way the events will match without huge amounts of very brittle phaffing about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this : https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/rKrMVV

passed selected value in **selectMake** functions so you can get value and id both. Once get id, just match it with numeric value and as per that, it will assign the value to **#make_**

**JS**

```
var i = 0;

function selectMake(e) {
    var matches = $(e).attr('id').match(/\d/);
    var y = $(e).val();
    if (matches === null) {
        var i = '';
    } else {
        var i = matches[0];
    }
    if (y == "2018") {
        $("#make" + i + "").html("<option value='make1'>make 1</option><option value='make2'>make 2</option>");
    } else if (y == "2017") {
        $("#make" + i + "").html("<option value='make3'>make 3</option><option value='make4'>make 4</option>");
    }
}
var i = 1;
$("#add_vehical").click(function() {
    $("#add_vehical_section").replaceWith("<div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'><span class='label-input100'>Year *</span><div><select  class='js-select2' id='year" + i + "' name='year[]' onchange='selectMake(this)'> <option value=''>Please choose Year</option> <option>2018</option>  <option>2017</option></select><div class='dropDownSelect2'></div></div> </div><div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'><span class='label-input100'>Make *</span><div><select class='js-select2' id='make" + i + "' name='make[]' onchange='selectModel()'><option value=''>Please chooses Make</option></select><div class='dropDownSelect2'></div></div></div>");
    i++;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
                <span class="label-input100">Year *</span>
                <div>
                    <select class="js-select2" id="year" name="year[]" onchange="selectMake(this)" >
                        <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
                        <option>2018</option>
                        <option>2017</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
                <span class="label-input100">Make *</span>
                <div>
                    <select class="js-select2" id="make" name="make[]" onchange="selectModel()">
                        <option value="">Please chooses Make</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <div class="wrap-input100" id="add_vehical_section"> </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
                <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_vehical">
                    <span>
                        Add another Vehicle
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what are attributes e and i?

Comment: can you please explain the code? just the first part.

Comment: one last help please. can you explain this statement `var matches = $(e).attr('id').match(/\d/);`

Comment: yeah this will check for numeric value in your id like year1, year2 or year and if find match with make1, make2 or make respectively

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't rely on dynamic *id* to attach event handlers. You can take advantage of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically.

Instead of relying on ID selector to target elements, learn to use DOM traversal methods i.e. `.closest()`, `.parents()` ... to target desired element.

Here in example, I have created a `hiddenContiner` div to fetch the HTML which needs to appended.

```js
$("#add_vehical").click(function() {
  $('.hiddenContiner')
    .clone() //Clone node
    .removeClass('hiddenContiner') //remove class
    .addClass('container') //add class
    .appendTo('.selectContiner'); //Append to common conatiner
});

$('.selectContiner').on('change', '.year', function() {
  var y = $(this).val();
  var make = $(this)
    .closest('.container') //Travse up to common parent
    .find('.make'); //target make element
  if (y == "2018") {
    make.html("<option value='make1'>make 1</option><option value='make2'>make 2</option>");
  } else if (y == "2017") {
    make.html("<option value='make3'>make 3</option><option value='make4'>make 4</option>");
  }
});

$('.selectContiner').on('change', '.make', function() {
  var make = $(this).val();
  //Do your thing
  
});
```

```css
.hiddenContiner {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectContiner">
  <div class="hiddenContiner">
    <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
      <span class="label-input100">Year *</span>
      <div>
        <select class="js-select2 year" name="year[]">
          <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
          <option>2018</option>
          <option>2017</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
      <span class="label-input100">Make *</span>
      <div>
        <select class="js-select2 make" name="make[]">
          <option value="">Please chooses Make</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
      <span class="label-input100">Year *</span>
      <div>
        <select class="js-select2 year" name="year[]">
          <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
          <option>2018</option>
          <option>2017</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
      <span class="label-input100">Make *</span>
      <div>
        <select class="js-select2 make" name="make[]">
          <option value="">Please chooses Make</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100" id="add_vehical_section"> </div>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_vehical">
    <span> Add another Vehicle  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the one with .clone()

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar, You can add any where in HTML better outside the cointainer and make sure its hidden